# What did the first humans tell their children about the Matrix and the real world?

Tags: the-matrix

When the first humans were plugged into the Matrix, they would obviously notice some differences, such as the level of technology available. When they started to have children in the Matrix, is there any canon evidence that they told their children about the Matrix?

Did they recorded the events that happened in the real world inside the matrix to pass on, but it simply got lost and forgotten because of a [reboot](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80208/does-the-machine-intelligence-reboot-our-genuine-knowledge-of-a-i)?

Comment: This begs another obvious question....

Comment: I think the premise of your question might be flawed. The purpose of the Matrix is to control what humans perceive as reality and this can't happen if humans are aware that they are plugged into it. Therefore, I believe all new humans are plugged in from birth while all pre-Matrix humans are hunted by the machines.

Comment: @awells - What about the first humans plugged into it, the ones we see in the Animatrix, did those people have their memory wiped so they don't remember?

Comment: @SinsofVodianova I haven't seen the Animatrix so I can't say, but I can't imagine why the machines would knowingly want to plug in someone who is aware that the Matrix is a simulation and keep them there long enough to bear children and pass down that knowledge.

Comment: @awells - If you get the chance, watch The Second Renaissance Part 1&2, it shows people being plugged into the matrix after the war. If their minds are wiped, it's not shown or stated, but I think most likely that's what happened. The machines are shown experimenting on humans, so it's possible they found a way to make the Matrix tamper or manipulate their memories to suppress them. By the time they stated having children, and the first humans died off, it won't be a problem.

Comment: We know from the deal Cypher made with the agents that the machines are capable of wiping memories for people they plug into the Matrix. There's no good reason to believe that someone the machines plugged into the Matrix would remember anything.